# JQuery Mobile Renders Incorrectly on my Rails Development Server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out this bug. All my widgets in JQuery Mobile render incorrectly on my development server, but when I push changes to heroku everything is fine. I tried deleting my tmp folder in rails but it still renders strangely.

Here are screen shots of my development server and the heroku one:

[image: Development Server]

[image: Production Server on Heroku]

I think it has something to do with the asset pipeline, but I have no idea what might be causing it.

Comment: Have you checked /public/assets folder? Delete it.

Comment: Thank you. This is what was wrong! Don't know how I missed it

Comment: Made a pretty answer for your liking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you delete your public/assets folder. Compiled css and js will overshadow your changes